# Identify groups that contain null, or do not, or contain both null and non-null values

Tags: sql, group-by

How do you group by column A and get only groups where B is never null?  Using SQL Server 2012.

For

```
A        B
Car      Radio
Car      Battery
Sedan    NULL
Sedan    Battery
Boat     NULL
Boat     NULL
```

I want a query that returns

```
A        
CAR
```

And I'd also want a query that returns groups where all are NULL (1 row from my sample, Boat).  I can see doing it with a bunch of subqueries, but it seems like there should be some straightforward syntax like [this is just made up] "HAVING (NOT EXIST B IS NULL)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `having` clause.  Here is one way:

```
select A
from table t
group by A
having count(*) = count(B);
```

You can also use:

```
having sum(case when b is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Once again you prove yourself better than Google, thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are some additional ways (join, not exists, not in), but you might be better off sticking to aggregation.

`join` method:

```
select distinct x.a
  from tbl x
  left join (select a from tbl where b is null) y
    on x.a = y.a
 where y.a is null
```

`not exists` method:

```
select distinct a
  from tbl t
 where not exists (select 1
          from tbl x
         where x.b is null
           and x.a = t.a)
```

`not in` method:

```
select disinct a
  from tbl
 where a not in (select a from tbl where b is null)
```